# Simple BPM or Workflow in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, business-process-management

I have a requirement to route between different pages in a mobile app (hybrid) based on the output from one page. The routing should be configurable, able to be updated independently of the App and ideally be able to edited visually.

Server-side this is handled by BPM Solutions (jBPM, IBM BPM, etc), however on the client-side I can't find anything suitable.

What I need is a JSON based set of rules that define which page to route to if a set of conditions are met. For example, if on page1 I have 2 fields: `name` and `age` and the User clicks Next then the rules might define that if `age >= 21` then route to page2, however if `age < 21` route to page3.

Is there any technology out there that currently does this? I've seen that there are Javscript Rules Engines such as [Nools](https://npmjs.org/package/nools), but they aren't BPM-like enough. Please don't suggest writing it myself - that's already being seriously considered.

Comment: I do not understand the requirement, to do it clientside. Using an ordinary MVC-framework on the server should do the trick. Your mobile app does a POST and the decision, where the flow continues,i.e. what html is served, is made on the server, so the client doesn't have to know any rules. If your serverside is done in Java, maybe http://www.springsource.org/spring-web-flow is of some help

Comment: @Lilith2k3 it's a mobile App that is potentially offline. All HTML pages are stored in the App bundle and the decision of which page to load is made by the 'rules'

Answer (score 0):

BPM isn't designed for "page flow". Most do include some sort of page flow technology for their own UIs, but I don't know of any that really promote that as a feature for building UIs in other technologies.

Fundamentally, what you are looking for is an MVC framework. You have your pages (views) and assumably you have your model already, but you are looking for a controller to link them together.

I'm aware of Cordova conceptually, but I don't have any hands-on experience so I don't feel comfortable making a flat out recommendation. I do know that Sencha Touch has some MVC functionality, and that it works fairly well with Cordova/PhoneGap, so that might be a direction for you to start in. Even if that doesn't work out for you, I can see that "Cordova MVC" and "PhoneGap MVC" provide several links and examples that seem very close to your use case.

Comment: Thanks. I know Cordova, Sencha and MVC well. It would be like having a Controller that was configurable with XML/JSON. In this context it is very much BPM or call it WorkFlow if you prefer.